# How to Commit Change to Local Repo Without Change Being Pushed to Remote Repo with Git

Tags: git

In my Git repository, I have a file that needs to contain the location of my working directory.  This will vary for each person who clones the repository, and it is important that this particular file has the right (unique) directory for each user.  Most of the file's contents are common for all users, other than the unique filepath.

Note that we can't maintain a different file (unique file name or file location within Git) per user, due to the fact that our tools search for that particular file location and file name.

The way that we work around this currently is to update the filepath to point to our working directory and then we never commit this update.  We leave it as a local change and when we pull or merge branches, we stash that local change to avoid any conflicts.  When the pull/merge is complete, we pop the stash.  Here is an example workflow, where we commit local changes to one branch (such as a feature branch) and then merge those to another branch (such as master).  We push all changes to both branches and we use `git stash` and `git stash pop` to hide the local change during this process.

```
// starting in branch named "original_branch"
git commit // our other changes that we do want to share with others
git stash  // stash the one file with the updated user directory
git pull
git push
git checkout another_branch
git pull
git merge original_branch
git push
git stash pop
```

To me, this is only a minor nuisance, because the workflow above works just fine.  But since I work with a team, work arounds like this end up leading to mistakes, and then I need to spend time helping folks resolve conflicts and other Git issues, rather than doing my actual work.  It would be ideal if I could somehow have each user commit their version of the file with the updated filepath into their local repository without that change going to the remote repository when they push other changes.  This doesn't seem possible, but I'm hoping that someone is aware of a solution here.

This is what I'm imagining that the solution would look like:

```
vim special_file.txt // update just that one line in special_file.txt
git commit --local-only -- special_file.txt
git commit -- some_other_file.txt
git push // only pushes the update for some_other_file.txt
```

Of course, I just made up the `--local-only` option for `git commit`, but I'm hoping that someone is aware of something similar.  I've checked Google and Stack Overflow, but no one seems to have asked a similar question.

---

**EDIT:** So far, most of the suggestions that have come up have been related to solutions that are not Git-based (e.g. symbolic links).  I originally wanted a Git-based solution as I described above because it would solve my problem while also accounting for a number of other constraints that I haven't yet mentioned.  Let me enumerate the other constraints here, so that they can be taken into consideration as we try to come up with a solution.

1. The tool is not owned by me or my team, so we can't change its behavior.
2. Each Git clone needs to correspond to a unique directory.  That is, it can't be a common clone that is shared by multiple users.
3. All users share the same file system, so using a fixed directory would violate restriction (2).
4. Each user ID might correspond to multiple Git clones, so we can't set up our clone as a directory (or symbolic link), with a fixed name within our home directories, because that would only allow one Git clone per user ID.
5. The tool can't expand environment variables to get the file path.
6. The file path *must* be in this particular file.  We can't include another file that contains the path.
7. This file *should* be tracked in Git, so that we can have version control for the contents of the file (other than the one line that contains the file path).
8. The tool accesses the file from a symbolic link that exists outside of the working directory.  This means that we can't use a relative file path, because the tool would end up looking at a path relative to the symbolic link, rather than looking at a path relative to the actual file in the working directory.
9. The solution will need to be implemented by multiple people, so the solution needs to be relatively easy, simple, and painless.  For example, expecting each person to create multiple user ID's and switch between them when they want to switch tasks would be too complicated.
10. There are many files like this in our Git repository, so it would be ideal if we could find a solution that does not require additional human effort for each file.

Comment: Of course the other option is to leave it as an untracked file, so that we never have issues with pushing or merging changes causing conflicts.  This would take away the benefit of source control, so I don't want to go that route, since this is a large and important file.

Comment: adding a level of indirection may help here.

Comment: The problem here is that the presence of a file will change the sha for a commit. So, this solution would require the same commit to have a different sha on each host,  and that would break git at a fundamental level.  I think the solution here will involve taking a step back,  considering how this is an xy problem,  perhaps, and finding a different way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I'm on board with @DonBranson here. Can you not just make a folder that would exist on all user systems... and name it all the same?

Comment: @JacobH The idea is that this file points our tools to each user's local checkout so that they can run simulations in isolation prior to committing and pushing their updates.  Having a single location to point to would force us to commit changes before we have had a chance to try them

Comment: @TimJohns - I'm trying to brainstorm, but don't have an actual answer yet. What about having a separate, local repo at a fixed location on each person's host, then either include that as a submodule, or a reference to that fixed location?

Comment: @DonBranson We log into a VPN for our work.  So there isn't a way to use a fixed filepath that is unique to each person, because we are sharing a single file system.  If we worked on our own individual machines, this would have worked

Comment: @TimJohns - okay. If the OS is a Unix variant, maybe the location is ~/personal. Again, just brainstorming, and trying things out.

Comment: I suppose I should mention that some of our other tools solve this by using an environment variable.  For example, we might define something like this in our `.profile`:  `export GIT_DIRECTORY=/path/to/local/git/clone`.  This option isn't possible for this particular tool because it doesn't know how to use environment variables.

Comment: @DonBranson Good point.  So you could clone the Git repo inside your home directory (or put a symbolic link in the home directory that points to your personal Git clone).  Then inside the special file, you would just put `~/git_clone/`, which would work for everyone as long as they name the symbolic link the same way.  I think this would work if each user only had one Git clone.  But, in reality, each person has multiple clones for various reasons.  (For example you might have one clone for running a regression from a clean state and another clone for new development).

Comment: @TimJohns. gotcha. I'll be thinking about this. Hopefully someone will come up with a good solution. :)]

Comment: @DonBranson Much appreciated!  To be fair, I technically _could_ ask each user to request multiple user ID's, and each ID would correspond to a single clone.  That would require people to log in and out frequently when they switch tasks, which probably won't be a well-received option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you *really* want doesn't exactly exist, I'm afraid.  I recommend you take another look at some of the solutions you've ruled out, and figure out how to make them work.

The commits that are pushed to the origin simply cannot contain files that vary from host to host.  They can contain templates.  They can contain placeholders.  They can contain scripts used to generate the file from the environment.

You push back that "the tool works a certain way", but that assumes that the input to the tool has to be exactly what you get from `git checkout`; that seems very unlikely.

I suppose the tool could itself build the worktree by calling `git checkout`, and then not give you any opportunity to modify the worktree before making ridiculous assumptions that the files it received are localized for that machine.  In that case, I guess you could set up a smudge filter (via git attributes) that would inject the local values (taken from the environment, or a local file at a particular location outside the repo, or whatever) during the checkout process.  (The corresponding clean filter would have to make sure the local values got taken back out.)  This requires a lot of project-specific custom scripting, so beyond outlining the idea as above I can't offer much more detail.

But that's a lot of work to set up something that I honestly expect will break and cause weird problems when you least expect it; and it just seems very unlikely that it's necessary.

In git, a tracked file is a tracked file; its changes are shared, always.  So find a way to separate the local variations (which can't go in tracked files) from the globally-sharable changes (which can), and figure out how to make your tools integrate with that.

By the way, I predict someone will suggest using the `skip-worktree` and/or `assume-unchanged` flags of the index.  It's a bad idea.  Not what those flags are for, requires manual setup of every repo, and will cause errors sooner or later.

Comment: Good point.  In Git, I could store a script which creates the file.  Then I would have each user run the script, but the actual generated file would not be tracked in Git.  This is definitely a viable solution.  What I don't like about it is that it requires some setup effort on my part and it requires each user to call this script after every `git pull` (unless if that step can be automated as well).  Note that there's not just one file that this problem applies to.  There are many files, but for simplicity, I only mentioned one file.

Comment: I've never heard of Git attributes or smudge filters.  [This](https://www.juandebravo.com/2017/12/02/git-filter-smudge-and-clean) page gave a quick overview and it does sound like a reasonable solution.